# Make my combobox replace words in .txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox with two resolution (1600x900 and 1280x720), I want them to replace "-screen-width XXXX -screen-height YYY" by the resolution chosen , in my TXT file when I press the "Save and Close" boutton, for the moment I've tried anything because I'm a real beginner at coding, it's my first Program I ever made.
Basically, my program will be an easy way to edit launch options for guys who don't know them
This is what I have in "InitializeComponent();"

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listResolution.Add("1600x900");
        listResolution.Add("1280x720");

        widthChoose = 1280;
        heightChoose = 720;
        windowed = true;

        foreach (String item in listResolution)
        {
            ResolutionBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This is what I have for my "Save and Close" boutton (The text replace doesn't work)

```
private void SaveClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Windowed.IsChecked == true)
            windowed = true;
        else
            windowed = false;

        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"Resources\arguments.txt");
        text = text.Replace("-screen-fullscreen 1", "-screen-fullscreen 0");
        File.WriteAllText("arguments.txt", text);

        this.Close();
```

And I have no event for my comboBox

```
private void ResolutionBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Content of my "arguments.txt"

> -screen-fullscreen 0 -screen-width 1600 -screen-height 900

Comment: Why down vote ? :/

Comment: Without the content of arguments.txt and your desired output for each resolution, there's no way to answer this question

Comment: Ok thank you I've edited it :)

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. Also "remplace" is not a word: do you mean "replace" or "emplace"? Start by stating (as if you were defining for a user) what you want to happen; then show what you have tried; then say what that is producing and finally what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you, I'm really sorry, Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before

```
File.WriteAllText("arguments.txt", text);
```

Add these :

First we take the selected resolution (not sure the purpose of listResolution there)

```
var selectedResolution = ResolutionBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

split it to width and height

```
var split = selectedResolution.Split('x');
widthChoose = split[0];
heightChoose = split[1];
```

then replace 1600 & 900 with the new values :

```
text = text.Replace("1600",widthChoose)
```

continue with height.

Comment: `split[0];` display as an error, is it ok if I put this instead ? `widthChoose = Int32.Parse(split[0]);`

Comment: Oops, yeah I forgot your width & height are integer there.